# Volume of a spinning top defined by a sphere and cone

Tags: integration

I have a concern related to this question.

Find the volume bounded above the cone $x^2 + y^2 = 3z^2$
and below the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2z$. I understand the sphere can be rewritten as $x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2 = 1$ or as $z = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.

My problem is representing the region in Cartesian Coordinates, do I need to evaluate using 2 separate triple integrals? Since along z both the upper and lower hemispheres of the sphere, as well as the upper half of the cone are boundaries to z. The upper boundary would be $z = 1 + \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, however the lower boundary is a combination of $z = 1 - \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ (from the sphere), and $z = \sqrt{\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{3}}$ (from the cone). Or is there another way to evaluate using just one triple integral?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and write the equation of the cone as $r=\pm\sqrt{3} z$. and the equation of the sphere as $r=\pm \sqrt{1-(z-1)^2}$. You can then write the volume as a simple integral $V=\int \pi r(z)^2 dz$. All you need is to plot the top in the $r-z$ coordinate, in order to get the integration limits